# How can I get Sinatra to store the last request made to it

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This is a bit of a weird question, but I'm trying to write a custom mocking library using Sinatra. I'd very much like my library to be able to store the last request made to it, but I'm having a really hard time getting Sinatra to do so. Has anyone else encountered this particular problem? And before you ask, using Webmock is not an option.

Comment: do you have a database?

Comment: Not in this scenario. Ideally the request should just be stored in memory.

Comment: HTTP is stateless by design so you'll need to persist the request somewhere.  Database, a file, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I just wrote some Rack Middleware to keep track of it.

```
module MockService
  class StoreLastRequest
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      @@last_request = { method: env['REQUEST_METHOD'], uri: env['REQUEST_URI'] }
      @app.call(env)
    end

    def self.last_request
      @@last_request
    end
  end
end
```